# Using Newton’s method to approximate a point $x$ such that $7 \sin x=x + \cos x$

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

I'm comfortable using polynomials for this method, but for sin and cos, would I be using the correct process below? I've pulled this example from an old textbook and was perplexed on how to carry this out.

**My work so far**

The derivative of $f$, which is

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(7 \sin x)=7 \cos x$$

And, applying Newton's method to the below table.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x_n& f(x_n) & f'(x_n) & \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} & x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\ \hline
x_1=3 & 0.9878400564 & −6.929947476 & −0.1425465431 & 3.142546543 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Should I proceed this way, or should I actually be using $\tan x_n$ to make it simpler? I know that

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'x_n)}=x_n-\frac{7\sin x_n}{7\cos x_n}=x_n-\tan x_n$$

Thus

$$x_1=3$$
$$x_2=x_1-\tan x_1=3-\tan 3$$
$$=3.142546543$$

Comment: You need to use a function with roots equal to this equation such as$$f(x)=7\sin{(x)}-x-\cos{(x)}$$

Comment: Thanks Peter. That's precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: Once you have settled on a function as above, the next detail is choosing an initial approximation to the root you want to locate more precisely with Newton iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)= 7 \sin x-x - \cos x$. Then, $f’(x)=7\cos x -1+\sin x$ and the first iteration is

$$x_1=3,\>\>\> f(3)= -1.022, \>\>\>f’(3)=-7.789,\>\>\>
x_2=x_1-\frac{f(3)}{f’(3)}= 2.869$$

Comment: Thanks Quanto. I just had a go at this and received the same results. Glad to know that I'm on the right track! \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x_n& f(x_n) & f'(x_n) & \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} & x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\ \hline
x_1=3 & −1.022167447 & −7.788827468 & 0.1312350866 & 2.868764913 \\ \hline
\end{array}